# Creating 2-D vector with values from another 2-D vector

Tags: c++, vector, 2d-vector

I have a 2-D vector called cosmic_ray_events that has a size equal to 898281 and I created another 2-D vector called high-energy_cosmic_rays. I put in a check in cosmic_ray_elements that filters out values that are less than 100 and are located at cosmic_ray_events[i][3]. If the value is greater than 100 then I would like to transfer all the elements associated with cosmic_ray_event[i][j] to another 2-D vector or resize this current 2-D vector so that it only contains vectors that had cosmic_ray_events[i][3] greater than 100. I get a segmentation fault when I try to set cosmic_ray_events[i][j] equal to another 2-D vector. I am not sure how to transfer the elements from one 2-D vector to another without getting a segmentation fault.

```
vector<vector<double> > high_energy_cosmic_rays(HE_CR, vector<double>(9,0));
for(int i = 0; i < cosmic_ray_events.size(); i++)
{
    if(cosmic_ray_events[i][3] >= 100.)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            high_energy_cosmic_rays[i][j] = cosmic_ray_events[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That segmentation fault is an *immediate* indicator you should be running your code in a debugger. When it breaks, the ensuing stack-trace could be quite educational in discovering where your assumptions about your code and workflow are wrong. That said, your resulting vector is indexed using the same `i` as the input one. Don't you want to be pushing those copies into an initially *empty* vector of vectors ?

Comment: At first glance HE_CR is not equal to cosmic_ray_events vector size. Hence out of bounds access.

Comment: What is the difference between using pushback and setting the 2-d vectors equal to each other? Also, I worded my question wrong because I know why the segmentation fault occurs but I am unsure of a way to get around it, if that makes sense.